# docker ( prisma ) Can't reach database server at `db`:`5432`

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

consider this docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  pg-prisma-rest:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=prisma_pg
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=benchmark
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  app:
    stdin_open: true
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    depends_on:
      - pg-prisma-rest
    ports:
      - "3050:3000"

volumes:
  postgres:
```

and the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
COPY package*.json ./
COPY . .

RUN yarn
RUN npx prisma migrate dev --name "init"
RUN npx prisma generate
```

when I run this docker file, face this error: 
`Can't reach database server at localhost:5432`

but if I comment the `app:` part
and do `docker compose up -d` the server status is Up and when run the `yarn start` in my machine, it works nicely :)

also to make sure that the `pg-prisma-rest` can be up,
i did `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)`
and `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)` and result is the same. ( maybe useful in some cases )

Is something missing in the docker file?

**EDIT** : 
according to the comments I edited the compose.yml and the Dockerfile and still it did not connect. changed `localhost` to `db` and moved migration to the `compose.yml` and also used [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh)  
compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    entrypoint: ["wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--"]
    # Use the original command of the app as an argument to the script
    command: ["yarn", "start:migrate"]

volumes:
  postgres:
```

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-bookworm-slim
COPY dataset ./dataset
COPY tsconfig.json ./
# COPY --from=dataPath ./dataset
WORKDIR /src/app
COPY package*.json yarn.lock ./
COPY prisma ./prisma/
RUN yarn 
COPY . .
compose. yaml file uses the docker-compose up command
# Copy the wait-for-it.sh script
COPY wait-for-it.sh /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh
# Make it executable
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh

EXPOSE 3000
```

and the package.json:

```
{
    ...
    
    "scripts": {
        "start": "NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=8192' ts-node -r dotenv/config index.ts",
        "start:prod": "node dist/main",
        "build": "rimraf ./build && tsc",
        "start:migrate": "prisma migrate deploy && yarn start",
        "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only src/server.ts",
        "studio": "prisma studio"
    }
}
```

and the result:

```
 wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for db:5433
prisma-express-rest-db-1   | yarn run v1.22.19
prisma-express-rest-db-1   | $ prisma migrate deploy && yarn start
prisma-express-rest-db-1   | Environment variables loaded from .env
prisma-express-rest-db-1   | Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
prisma-express-rest-db-1   | Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "prisma", schema "list" at "db:5432"
prisma-express-rest-db-1   | 
prisma-express-rest-db-1   | Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `db`:`5432`
```

Comment: Try updating the connection string part in your `app` from localhost:5432 to pg-prisma-rest:5432 instead. Something to do with how network works in Docker

Comment: @DriLLFreAK100 the same result

Comment: Many problems here. 1. DB host should be `pg-prisma-rest` (but not `localhost`) if you trying to access it from another container. 2. `depends_on` is useless here, because `app` will be started immediately after `pg-prisma-rest` started, but Postgres need time to start DB inside container. So, healthcheck should be implemented. 3. The most weird thing is that you are trying to apply DB migrations on image building, but not on container running time. Compose file should be completely refactored.

Comment: You can't run migrations in a Dockerfile (at all, on any database technology in any language) since the image build isn't dependent on the database running and isn't on the same Docker network.  The "how do I run migrations" question discusses this further for the Prisma case.  The "error P1001" question further discusses why the database URL isn't `localhost`, again with a focus on Prisma.